# ASP.NET MVC record status

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm building auction system in ASP.NET MVC.

How do I get the Status of my Item class to display "Finished" when the end date has passed.

So far I have created the Item model:

```
    public class Item
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be between {1} and {2} characters length", MinimumLength = 6)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public decimal StartingPrice { get; set; }

    [StringLength(4000, ErrorMessage = "Description must be no longer than {1}")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }

    public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Bid> Bids { get; set; }

}
```

and a ViewModel:

```
    public class ViewItemViewModel
{
   // [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    private DateTime endDate;
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime EndDate
    {
        get { return endDate; }
        set
        {
            TimeSpan span = (value - DateTime.Now);
            TimeLeft = String.Format("{0} d, {1} h, {2} m, {3} s left", span.Days, span.Hours, span.Minutes, span.Seconds);
            endDate = value;
        }
    }

    public string TimeLeft { get; private set; }

    [StringLength(4000, ErrorMessage = "Description must be no longer than {1}")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: and what you have tried so far?

Comment: Have a look ast the answer in this SO post for some ideas... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369897/how-to-raise-event-with-timer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm struggling to understand what you're asking, however **assuming that you want to only allow bids when the auction is not finished** then add a small form for bidding to your Item Details view (Auction Item page), which passes either a **Bid CreateModel** or **ItemID + Bid Amount** to a Bid action on the controller.

Your controller action could be something like:

```
public ActionResult Bid(int itemid, decimal bidAmount)
    {
        Item item = db.Items.Find(itemid);
        if (item.EndDate < DateTime.Now)
        {
            // Too late, the auction is over
            return View("AuctionComplete");
        }
        if (bidAmount > item.Bids.OrderByDescending(b => b.Value).First().Value);
        {
            // Valid bid, add to db and return view
            db.Bids.Add(new Bid() { ItemID = itemid, Value = bidAmount });
            db.SaveChanges();
            return View();
        }
        // There is a higher bid than this one already
        return View("Outbid");
    }
```

**Edit**

```
public string Status { get { return EndDate < DateTime.Now ? "Finished" : "Not Finished"; } }
```

I personally would implement a boolean property named 'Finished' or 'Complete', and then use that within other calculations/decisions. Example:

```
public bool Finished { get { return EndDate < DateTime.Now; } }
public string Status { get { return Finished ? "Finished" : "Live"; } }
```

**Edit 2**

You could have a service running that queries the database with something along the lines of:

```
UPDATE Items SET Status = 'Finished' WHERE EndDate < GETDATE()
```

Or you could create a computed column or view to calculate the value within the database at runtime.

Comment: I don't know when and how I could change auction status to finished.

Comment: You can generate the status at runtime/on request using logic (see my edited answer above), or have a separate service that checks and updates the statuses periodically (not recommended in this scenario as it's an auction).

Comment: But I want to change status value in database also. This only returns string.

Comment: could you show atleast one?

Comment: Apologies, StackOverflow prevented me from editing my comment.
You can accomplish this in a variety of ways. You could use a service that periodically queries the database to update the status of all Items based on their EndDate, or use a view or computed column in SQL Server, or just do it programmatically. See Edit 2.